# Set first configurable product as default image

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

I have a product with different configuration, but my default product can't be buy (it has no image).

I want to show on the store the first configurable product of this not available for purchase product instead of an empty image

[image]

Comment: do you want to change place holder image of product?

Comment: I possible yes (but the image of the first variation)

Comment: place holder image of product change from configuration. You can check.

Comment: I don't understand sorry